The book where someone can serve a sentence in advance
I read a novel about a system where a person could volunteer to serve a sentence working on an inhospitable alien planet in advance of committing a crime, if they survive.
The protagonist chose to see a sentence for murder.
He survived and returned and pretty much everyone he knew expected they were the one he planned to kill.
I cannot remember the title or author.

In roughly which year did you read this?

A novelette, not a book: "Time in Advance" by William Tenn https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74024/man-serves-a-sentence-for-the-murder-he-will-be-allowed-to-commit-in-the-future

Hi John and welcome to the SF&F SE :-) Please let us know if this is your story so we can mark it as a duplicate.

William Tenn's "Time In Advance".  First published 1958 in an eponymous collection with three other stories.

This story was published in the August 1956 issue of Galaxy Science Fiction. The story presents a future in which citizens serve out sentences for crimes they have not yet committed. Two "pre-criminals", "Blotto" Otto Henck and Nicholas Crandall, manage against all the odds to serve out two full terms for murder in an off-world penal colony. They are returned to Earth as minor celebrities with the right to kill one person each.

